# erro ao executar o kivy designer, No module named 'designer'?

Tags: python, python-kivy

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
como resolver esse erro no kivy designer ?
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]

Comment: Estamos no [pt.so], então traduza sua pergunta acessando o link [edit]. Ao fazer isso, busque, também, colocar na pergunta o código que gerou o erro e copie a mensagem de erro para cá, não deixe-a como imagem. No mais, faça o [tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa instalar o kivy designer seguindo alguns passos ditos na documentação oficial.
Siga a URL:

[Link instalação kivy designer](http://kivy-designer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)